# InlineKeyboardMarkup Telegram bot (pyTelegramBotAPI)

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I am making a bot on pyTelegramBotAPI, I need to generate a list of buttons and write it into the keyboard (So that there are 5 buttons in a row). How should I do it? I have a code:

````
def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    buttons = []
    for i in range(-12, 15):
        if i < 0:
            button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(f'{i}', callback_data=f'{i}')
        elif i == 0:
            button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(f'±{i}', callback_data=f'{i}')
        else:
            button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(f'+{i}', callback_data=f'{i}')
        buttons.append(button)
        if len(buttons) == 5:
            # here i want to add buttons in a row
 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Здравствуйте, <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>. Для начала необходимо настроить часовой пояс. Выберите разницу во времени относительно UTC (Москва: "+3", Владивосток: "+10", Исландия: "+1")', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)```
````

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly isn't working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Everything works, I just need someone to tell me how to add a list of buttons to 1 row of Inline keyboard

Answer (score 1):

I can advise you to create a separate module responsible for keyboards.
[example of modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty8TR.png)
This way you can separate the logic of handlers from the logic of keyboards.
As torrua wrote earlier, you can use the [keyboa](https://habr.com/ru/post/522720/) (how to use keyboa) library.
or write the functions yourself to create keyboards and buttons in it.
What you need to know for this:

```
telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup() # creates an empty keyboard.
telebot.type.InlineKeyboardButton()  # creates a button for the keyboard created earlier.

.row() # determines the position of the buttons in the keyboard.
```

[example of function to get keyboards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvHSj.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easy with [keyboa](https://github.com/torrua/keyboa):

````python
from keyboa import Keyboa

def start():
    
    buttons = []

    for i in range(-12, 15):

        if i < 0:
            button = (f'{i}', i)
        elif i == 0:
            button = (f'±{i}', i)
        else:
            button = (f'+{i}', i)

        buttons.append(button)

    keyboard = Keyboa(items=buttons, items_in_row=5).keyboard

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Здравствуйте, <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>. Для начала необходимо настроить часовой пояс. Выберите разницу во времени относительно UTC (Москва: "+3", Владивосток: "+10", Исландия: "+1")', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=keyboard)```
````